# Pentaho report designer space bettween band border and element

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have question about Pentaho report designer.
I have band with subreport [report band](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmqwt.png) And when i set top border as solid for band i got the following [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZTwv.png) There is space between border band and first elements in band. Any ideas how to remove this space? Here is my [band](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nC7X.png)